# Dynamic class_name for has_many relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, orm

I'm trying to make has_many relation with dynamic class_name attribute

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ads, :class_name => ( lambda { return self.item_type } ) 
end
```

or

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ads, :class_name => self.item_type
end
```

But i got errors:

```
can't convert Proc into String
```

or

```
undefined method `item_type' for #<Class:0xb62c6c88>
```

**EDIT**
I have two different types of Ads

`LeaseAd`, `RentAd` they implemented using single table inheritance

Then i have `Category` of ads as nested set. I would like to specify dinamicly which type of ads belongs to `Category` object.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Next time, consider asking solutions for your root problem. I would make an `allowed_ad_types` habtm in the Category, enforcing validation on that habtm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
can't convert Proc into String
```

means that rails is expecting a String

```
undefined method `item_type' for #<Class:0xb62c6c88>
```

means that you didn't define `item_type` for the `Class`-object

I believe what you want here is not possible this way.

I would use something like singletable inheritance for the ads and its subtypes.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I understand these errors. I just explained my approaches. Is there any chance to set :class_name attribute dynamicly?

Comment: As I said, I believe it is not possible. I would use singletable inheritance

Answer (score 6):

You can try

```
def items
  item_type.constantize.where(category_id: id)
end
```