# has_one relation depending on user type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-one

I'm trying to create different profile types for my users.

I have a Users model.

`User` type has a `Profile` related, so it `has_one :profile` but, `Page` type has a `Page` related, so it `has_one :page`

But, I'm using the same `User` table for both, and I'm setting the account type.

I'd like to know, how to determine that relationship based on my user account type

### Edit

User model has_one :profile Profile belongs_to :user Page belongs_to :user Account type is either "User" (which goes to Profile model), or "Page" (which goes to Page model).

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile, :class_name => 'Here it should be either PROFILE or PAGE'
end

class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

I've been reading a bit through the API, and found :class_name, now my challenge is to dynamically determine it.

### Edit

Edited a bit the Page model and User model.

Comment: Please post your models with their associations. And with 'account type' do you mean 'profile'?

Comment: User model
has_one :profile

Profile
belongs_to :user

Page
belongs_to :user


Account type is either "User" (which goes to Profile model), or "Page" (which goes to Page model)

I've been reading a bit through the API, and found :class_name, now my challenge is to dynamically determine it.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, a `User` has an attribute `account_type` which is either an instance of `Page` or `User.profile`?

Comment: Exactly! But, in the Page model, doesn't have has_one :page. You can see the changes I made to my main post. Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: So what determines if a `User` has a `Page` or `User.profile` as its account type? What's the condition that sets `User.account_type`?

Comment: Yes! That's correct. The account type is set from a variable.
Getting the account type is not being a problem, in fact, I have it working.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a `proc` works?

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  TYPES = { 'user' => 'Profile', 'page' => 'Page' }
  has_one :profile, :class_name => proc { TYPES[self.type].constantize }
end
```

If this works consider adding a table to store the User types:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  TYPES = { 'user' => 'Profile', 'page' => 'Page' }
  has_one :profile, :class_name => proc { TYPES[self.type].constantize }
  belongs_to :user_type
end

class UserType < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
end
```

Comment: May be conditional validations will do it too. :) But Polymorphic is really good option on such cases.

Comment: Yes, but shouldn't it be the other way around? Sorry my English sometimes limits me. The Page or Profile belongs to the User, not the other way around.

Comment: I've tried lambda, and added to User model:
has_one :profile, :class_name => ( lambda {
    return TYPES[self.type]
  })

Comment: That looks like it's doing the trick. But my question now is, how does Rails decide what to use?

Comment: I don't know that one :) You can make a new question about that. Consider posting the answer you've found to your question for future reference.

Comment: I'm testing it, and I read the API for polymorphic. Sadly, it's not what I'm needing. Isn't there anyway to set the has_one :class_name dynamically? I think that's much easier.

Comment: `class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      TYPES = { 'user' => 'Profile', 'page' => 'Page' }
      has_one :profile, :class_name => "#{TYPES[self.type]}"
   end`

But I get "undefined method `key?' for nil:NilClass"

Comment: I think it's actually really close, thanks to you! :) Haha, but now I get this: uninitialized constant User::#<Proc:0x007fdd9c280dd0@/home/mauro/Projects/vdg/app/models/user.rb:10>

Comment: Hm, maybe what you want is not possible after all: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3045254/dynamic-class-name-for-has-many-relations

Comment: I ended up with TWO has_one, later on, I'll just check the account type and work with that. :/ I'll make a suggestion in the Rails dev site for this. Thanks again for SO MUCH help!